Filtering on Upvotes Needs to Be Fixed
Strange that when one filters on "no accepted answers", the added condition of "with no answers with upvotes" is automatically thrown in.
Let the user select his filter(s) instead of throwing in filters not specified.
As it is now, even a well-received puzzle with a wrong answer that has just 1 upvote will not show up anywhere, unless specifically searched for.
Try finding this one without a specific search:
You Don't See Me As My Age
Pretty frustrating.

As a workaround, use "hasaccepted:0" in the search bar

Thx lukas. Will do!

That's not a puzzling specific issue. And was raised as a bug when filters were originally added (~five years ago, so don't hold your breath for a fix). See here
